# VS+Qt 5.0 change to Qt Creator,but it can not find ui_*.h

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I created a Qt project with Visual studio+Qt , so the file is `**.vcxproj`.this condition,it works well.

Now i want write a file .pro, to add `+xml` to use `xml` function;also  i can open the project with Qt Creator

but ,no matter how I include these files  `ui_*.h` files under `./Generated` Files,it  recommend the errors:

```
d:\opf_gui\bsiopfqtgui\bsisuperopfqtgui\bsiopf_vsasession.h(16): fatal error C1083: 无法打开包括文件(mean:can not open included files):“ui_vsasession.h”: No such file or directory
1>  bsiopfwelcome_mainpage.cpp
```

here is part of my .pro content:

```
QT  += xml
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = QtGui
INCLUDEPATH += ../../fKernel   ../../fKernel/src  

Input
HEADERS +=  GeneratedFiles\ui_vsasession.h

FORMS += *_newsession.ui \
            ...
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have line `greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets` in your pro file? If not - add it.

Comment: Yes this is already added in

Comment: You do not need to add generated files to pro file. `HEADERS +=  GeneratedFiles\ui_vsasession.h` - this line is unwanted.

Comment: Thank you very very much, this problem confused me for a long time,today with your help ,it is solved,thanks~